# GitLab -ce: "Username has already been taken Username already exists"

Tags: gitlab

Gitlab version : 15.2.2

deleted a user and recreating same user give error

this is how i deleted it

gitlab-rails console

User.find_by(username: "myusername")

=> #<User id:3 @myusername>

User.delete(3)

After that I wanted to join again under the same name

"Username has already been taken Username already exists" even though the user does not exists.

I looked for a user with the same name but couldn't find it

This is how I found it.

gitlab-rails console

User.find_by(username: 'myusername')

=> nil

User.find_by(email: 'myusername@email.com')

=> nil

What should I do?

Comment: Try using the API instead of the rails console.

Comment: How do I use the API?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please confirm how this user was created? Can you please try the following command in `gitlab-rails console`.

```
User.find_by_any_email('EMAIL address')
Email.find_by_email('EMAIL address')
```

and see if you are able to find the records.

Comment: I've tried both but I get nil. It's nil, but I don't know why it says it's already in use when I sign up.

<User Id:3 @anothere mail> works well when an email that has not been deleted is entered.

Comment: This is now fixed. Can you please try this again and let me know if it works?